# How can you transfer a seed that crashed a fuzz test via text?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, fuzz-test

When you run a fuzzer and it crashes, what is a way that you can easily transfer the fuzz seed to the author of the PR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a fuzz-test crashes it will print the error stack. The top will give you an idea what caused the issue, and the bottom will provide you with a text-formatted version of the crashing fuzz seed.

```
fuzz: ../../src/wallet/test/fuzz/coinselection.cpp:120: void wallet::coinselection_fuzz_target(FuzzBufferType): Assertion `result_bnb->GetChange(coin_params.m_cost_of_change, CAmount{0}) == 0' failed.
==2010034== ERROR: libFuzzer: deadly signal
    #0 0x55c5cfab4841 in __sanitizer_print_stack_trace (/home/murch/Workspace/pr-27585/fuzz-build/src/test/fuzz/fuzz+0x1611841) (BuildId: 7e7dce8b351f3ad01c4e9815f15265d8d7a64c61)
    …
    [skipped]
    …
artifact_prefix='./'; Test unit written to ./crash-05d2df3cebde688a5114737869a65484cecd9f45
Base64: MP3//////wT/LzMBEABL////////Wv///yWyEABLAADoQP//PP//CAAAPQAAAAAAAAAAPQEAAAAAAAAA/V12+w==
```

To figure out what caused the crash, you can use run the fuzzer against just the crashing seed, and use your regular debugging approach e.g.:

```bash
$ FUZZ=coinselection src/test/fuzz/fuzz crash-05d2df3cebde688a5114737869a65484cecd9f45
```

If you are not the author of the PR that caused the crashing fuzz test, you can provide the fuzz seed to the other developer via the *base64* encoding at the bottom of the error message. Leave them for example instructions like this in a comment on the PR:

```bash
$ echo "MP3//////wT/LzMBEABL////////Wv///yWyEABLAADoQP//PP//CAAAPQAAAAAAAAAAPQEAAAAA AAAA/V12+w==" | base64 -d > crash.input
$ FUZZ=coinselection src/test/fuzz/fuzz crash.input
```

The string in the quotation marks is simply the base64 encoding from above.